# Set SelectedValues MVC to Select2 ListBoxFor

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, jquery-select2

I'm trying to create a select list to set authors of ebook, the first part is ok, i can set the values, select it and save.

but when i try edit, i not able to get the selected values! i don't know how to make it happens

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.EbookAutor, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.OsAutores, "Autor_ID", "Nome",null,(IEnumerable<int>) ViewBag.Selecteds), new { @class = "form-control", @data_size = "120" })
```

It's the 2 viewbags that i used to

```
 ViewBag.OsAutores = grAutor.SelectAll().Where(a => a.Ativo == true).OrderBy(a => a.Nome).ToList();
 ViewBag.Selecteds = grAutor.FindBy(a => a.EbookAutor.Where(b => b.Ebook_ID == id).Count() > 0).Select(m => m.Autor_ID).ToList();
```

Comment: Delete the `ViewBag.Selecteds` from you `SelectList` constructor - its ignored when you bind to a property. Its the value of the property your binding to that determines what is selected so if the values of the options are 1 to 10, and property `EbookAutor` is `[2, 5]`, then the 2nd and 5th options will be selected when you generate the view.

Comment: Hello, but how do i give the selected values? EbookAutor is one table between Ebook <- EbookAutor -> Autor... It's different of what i gives to select, i use Autors to fill the select

Comment: You seem to be getting the values you want with the code your assigning to `ViewBag.Selecteds` - so just set the value of `EbookAutor` to that result